# Postgres ctid to block count mismatch

Tags: postgresql, block, offset

I am using Postgres 9.4.5 and I detected corruption in one of my tables. I noticed this when running queries on a specific table caused the entire database to go into recovery mode. The symptoms lined up with those found in this article:

https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2010/06/01/tracking-down-database-corruption-with

I tried following the steps to zero out the corrupt block but after following the steps, I got a ctid of 507578.

```
database=# \set FETCH_COUNT 1
database=# \pset pager off
Pager usage is off.
database=# SELECT ctid, left(coded_element_key::text, 20) FROM coded_element WHERE ctid >= '(507577,1)';
    ctid    |   left   
------------+----------
 (507577,1) | 30010491
 (507577,2) | 30010507
 (507577,3) | 30010552
 (507577,4) | 30010556
 (507577,5) | 30010559
 (507577,6) | 30010564
 (507577,7) | 30010565
 (507577,8) | 30010625
 ...
 ...
 ...
 (507578,26) | 0A1717281.0002L270&.
 (507578,27) | L270&.*)0000.0000000
 (507578,28) | 30011452
 (507578,29) | -L0092917\x10)*(0117001
 (507578,30) | 0.00003840\x10)*)300114
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1908473862
```

The problem is that when I went to my /data/base directory and found the corresponding file for my table, the file was only 1073741824 bytes. With a block size of 8192 bytes this only gives me a block count of 131072, way under the 507578 value where the supposed corruption is. Is this the correct way to determine the block offset or is there a different way?

Comment: 507578 is not a `tid`. Can you [edit] the question and show the end of the `psql` output right before the problem happens?

Comment: https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.4.5&to=9.4.25&keywords=

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe, I've updated my question to cover that.

Comment: Note that the article you mention has moved here: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2010/06/tracking-down-database-corruption-with/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL stores the table data in files of 1GB in size.

Assuming that the result of

```
SELECT relfilenode
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = 'coded_element';
```

is 12345, those files would be called `12345`, `12345.1`, `12345.2` and so on.

Since each of these 1GB segments contains 131072 blocks, block 507578 is actually block 114362 in `12345.4`.

The data corruption is either in that block or the following one.

At this point, make sure you have a backup the complete data directory.

To zero out block 507578, you can use

```sh
dd if=/dev/zero of=12345.4 bs=8192 seek=114362 count=1 conv=notrunc,nocreat,fsync
```

If that doesn't do the trick, try the next block.

To salvage data from the block before zeroing it, you can use the [`pageinspect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html) extension.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, that was it! I was able to clear out the corrupted block and restore functionality.

Comment: Good. Test your hardware. Make sure to upgrade. Don't continue using this cluster - run a `pg_dumpall` and restore it to a new cluster. There couls still be some corruption somewhere.